# Calling unknown method: yii\web\UrlManager::addRules()

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-routing

I have worked in Yii 1 and now trying to use Yii2. I have installed composer and then installed basic app. But now I am getting this error when I try to access the basic app. How can I solve this issue?

Error is:

> Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException
>
> Calling unknown method: yii\web\UrlManager::addRules()

Comment: [Read carefully the documentation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/apps/basic#installation)

Answer (score -1):

ok I solved the problem installing yii2 in this way :

composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.*@dev"

composer create-project --prefer-dist --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic

Answer (score -1):

Check your composer.json file.
Section 'extra' should contain

`"extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
}`

then run `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.*@dev"` and `composer update`
it helped me